# Inclusion of code file in Github gollum does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: github, wiki

Has anyone managed to make this work? It appears that gollum has a problem with this. It refuses to load any file from git and all I get is an empty gray box.

From the documentation...

#### GITHUB SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTING

As an extra feature, you can syntax highlight a file from your repository, allowing
you keep some of your sample code in the main repository. The code-snippet is
updated when the wiki is rebuilt. You include github code like this:

````
```html:github/gollum/master/test/file_view/1_file.txt```
````

This will make the builder look at the **github user**, in the **gollum project**,
in the **master branch**, at path **test/file_view/1_file.txt**. It will be
rewritten to:

````
```html
<ol class="tree">
  <li class="file"><a href="0">0</a></li>
</ol>
```
````